# Change TextBox Array Color Background

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, textbox

hie I have an array of text boxes which are populated by a random number generator (1,49). I would like to have the each Textbox to change color according to a range of numbers. for example if the number is less than 10, the Textbox should be blue. If number is between  10 and 20 textbox should be green, etc. Ant one with an idea?
here is the code

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();
TextBox [] textboxes = new Control[]{TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3,TextBox4,TextBox5,TextBox6};

foreach(TextBox c in textboxes) 
    c.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to set the color of your textbox from the code-behind. And based on your requirement you can set the color of your textbox by setting `BackColor` property or you can set the style also like  `txtbox.Style.Add("background-color","blue");`.

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();
TextBox [] textboxes = new Control[]{TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3,TextBox4,TextBox5,TextBox6};

    foreach(TextBox c in textboxes){
    var number = RandomClass.Next(1,49);
        c.Text = number .ToString();
    if(number<10)
       c.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    else if(number>=10 && number <=20)
       c.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```